# Why do I get a "Could not resolve reference" when I use my XText grammar?

Tags: xtext

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar com.x.x.x.XxxDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate xxxDsl "http://www.x.x.x.com/xxx/xtext/XxxDsl"

Root:
    catalogs+=Catalog*
    instances+=Instance*
    ;

Catalog returns Catalog:
    'Catalog' name=ID
    '{'
    models+=Model*
    '}'
    ;

Model returns Model:
    'Model' name=ID
    ;

Instance returns Instance:
    'Instance'
    name=ID
    'of'
    model=[Model]
;
```

And here is my text:

```
Catalog myCatalog
{
    Model meteo
    Model storm
}

Instance wintermeteo of meteo
Instance strongstorm of storm
```

The 2 last lines are in error, `meteo` and `storm` being marked with:

```
Couldn't resolve reference to Model 'meteo'/'storm'
```

If I change my grammar so that the Models are directly in Root (and not inside Catalogs anymore) and update the text accordingly, then the models are correctly recognized.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Xtext builds qualified names. So if your models have a parent with a name then the models name will be parentname.modelname

You can either adapt the `IQualifiedNameProvider` (subclass and bind `DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider` or bind `SimpleNameProvider`) or you have to adapt the grammar to allow qualified names for the model reference

```
... model=[Model|FQN]
```

With

```
FQN: ID ("." ID)*;//pseudocode
```

Answer (score 1):

As Christian has mentioned, cross-reference relies on the attribute "name" of the element (the instance created by the rule), to avoid problems due to duplicates,  the default implementation of the name provider computes a qualified name, it concatenates the name of an element (Model) with the qualified name of its container (Catalog (Christian calls it parent)) recursively (root_name.catalog_name.model_name). The "name" of "meteo" is actually "myCatalog.meteo" (the rule Root has no "name="). If you don't want to adapt the IQualifiedNameProvider (to work only with simple names), you can adapt the grammar

```
... model=[Model|FQN]
...
FQN: ID ("." ID)*;
```

And now:

```
Catalog myCatalog
{
    Model meteo
    Model storm
}


Instance wintermeteo of myCatalog.meteo
Instance strongstorm of myCatalog.storm
```

should be accepted.